# NGINX: How to process one location using different directives and rules depending on content-type?

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

Is there a way, not workaround, to process one `location ~* <ADDRESS> {}` but with different value of `proxy_request_buffering` (on/off) depending on `content-type`?  For example, if `multipart/form-data` than `proxy_request_buffering` has to be `off`, and for other requests `on`. These kind of directives cannot be set dynamicly by variable or within IF condition. Hence, it should be something like one `location` as entrypoint that forwards requests to other `sub-locations` i suppose. But how can it be done? Please help.

It is application-specific thing, and one request type can be used for many purposes. That's why i cannot split them. Information about what type is stored within POST body. OR content-type is also good sign to decouple them.

The code example:

```
    location ~* /application/service$ {
        client_max_body_size '5000m';
        client_body_buffer_size '1m';

        proxy_request_buffering on;
        proxy_buffering on;

        rewrite_by_lua_file /etc/nginx/lua/service.lua;
        
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/common/reverse.conf;
        proxy_pass $proxy_address;
    }
```

The goal is to be able to set the derectives `client_max_body_size` and `proxy_request_buffering` based on `content-type`.

```
Client -bigfile----*       *--> sub-location (buffering is off)
                    \     /
                   location
                    /     \
Client -regular----*       *--> sub-location (buffering is on)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to process one location ~*  {} but with different value of proxy_request_buffering (on/off) depending on content-type

i met the same question. i think the easiest way to solve the problem is using nginx internal redirect mechanism. the code exmaple:

```
location @multi_part {
    internal;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_pass http://localserve;
}

location /kodo_test {
    rewrite_by_lua_block{
        if ngx.var.http_content_type == "multipart/form-data" then 
            return ngx.exec("@multi_part", nil)
        end 
    }
    proxy_buffering on;
    proxy_pass http://localserve;
}
```